# How does foreign key works?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

I have an problem with my schedule (date) which is it keeps being null.
So, basically my current situation is i have a seminar list which is the user must select from the gridview and also need to choose the schedule date (after the user click from the list seminar).

My problem is why the schedule date cannot bring over to the database which is being null after user make an payment.

my code here for list seminar,

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Panel1.Visible = true;
    List<Seminar> seminars = SeminarMgr.getAllSeminar();
    Seminar a = seminars[gvSeminar.PageSize * gvSeminar.PageIndex + gvSeminar.SelectedIndex];
    List<Schedule> schedules = ScheduleMgr.getAllScheduleById("");
    Schedule b = schedules[gvSchedule.SelectedIndex];
    List<Speaker> speakers = SpeakerDBMgr.getAllSpeaker();
    Speaker c = speakers[gvSeminar.SelectedIndex];

    if (Session["cart"] == null)
    {
        //member session of user
        ShoppingCart s = new ShoppingCart();
        s.Member = (Member)Session["user"];

        Session["cart"] = s;
    }
    //adding a seminar by user 
    ShoppingCart sc = (ShoppingCart)Session["cart"];
    sc.Seminar = a;
    sc.Seminar.Schedule = b;
    sc.Seminar.Speaker = c;




    //redirecting a new page to shoppingcartform.aspx
    Response.Redirect("ShoppingCartForm.aspx");

}
```

this code for my shopping cart form which is to make a payment,

```
    if (tbxName.Text != null && tbxCC.Text != null && ddlCCType.Text != null && tbxExpDate.Text != null)
    {
        ShoppingCart sc = (ShoppingCart)Session["cart"];
        sc.Name = tbxName.Text;
        if (rdbCash.Checked == true)
        {
            sc.OptionPay = rdbCash.Text;

        }else
        {
            sc.OptionPay = rdbCC.Text;
        }
        sc.CreditCard = tbxCC.Text;
        sc.CreditCardType = ddlCCType.Text;
        sc.SecurityCode = tbxCode.Text;
        sc.CCExpiryDate = tbxExpDate.Text;
        sc.Seminar.Schedule.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(tbxDate.Text);
        string a = lblAmount.Text;
        string b = a.Substring(1);
        lblAmount.Text = b;
        sc.TotalAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(lblAmount.Text);
        int Id = ShoppingCartDBMgr.purchaseSeminar(sc);
        lblOutput.Text = "Confirm. order id is " + Id;
        //display output for payment successfully
        //lblOutput.Text = "Payment Successfully!";
        //make it null for amount, date and session of cart after transaction are being successful
        lblAmount.Text = null;
        lblDate.Text = null;
        Session["cart"] = null;
        //send an email for confirmation
        //SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        //client.EnableSsl = true;
        //client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("inft3050@gmail.com", "inft.3050");

        //MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("inft3050@gmail.com", "andrian97@windowslive.com");
        //msg.Subject = "Payment confirmation";
        //msg.Body = "Thanks for joining our seminar!";
        //client.Send(msg);
    }
    else
    {
        //display an output if payment is not valid
        lblOutput.Text = "Payment is not valid!";
    }
```

This code is my database manager to insert a payment,

```
public static int purchaseSeminar(ShoppingCart sc)
{
    int Id = -1;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    try
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = con;

        command.CommandText = "insert into Payment (payment_name, payment_ccNo, payment_ccType, payment_ccCode, payment_expDate, payment_price, payment_optionPay, payment_date, participant_email, sch_id) values (@payment_name, @payment_ccNo, @payment_ccType, @payment_ccCode, @payment_expDate, @payment_price, @payment_optionPay, @payment_date, @participant_email, @sch_id)";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_name", sc.Name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_ccNo", sc.CreditCard);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_ccType", sc.CreditCardType);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_ccCode", sc.SecurityCode);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_expDate", sc.CCExpiryDate);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_price", sc.TotalAmount);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_optionPay", sc.OptionPay);
        DateTime da = DateTime.Now;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_date", da);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@participant_email", sc.Member.Email);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sch_id", sc.Schedule.Id);
        con.Open();

        if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            command.CommandText = "Select @@identity";
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
        }
        return Id;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that a cleartext credit card number and security code being stored in a database? Because that looks like a cleartext credit card number and security code being stored in a database.

Comment: You are retrieving cart from session `ShoppingCart sc = (ShoppingCart)Session["cart"];` , chaging it by setting its Schedule and Speaker properties but  not saving it back to the session. That's why when you are saving it to database schedule is null which gets saved in the database.

Comment: And your code is saving only payment information. Seminar related information is nowhere saved in the code.

Comment: where is the scheduleddate column in the table Payment ?? I noticed that you are not providing the scheduleddate nor its value.

Comment: basically, sch_id will contains an schedule date but i don't know why it's keep null in database manager of purchaseSeminar